# What do I need if I want to play with 2 VM Win Servers?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, networking, virtualization

Im new in the server world. I would like to make 2 virtual servers so I can play with them. What do I need? I have here a Win 7 system. Is it enough to install on this Win 7 system the free VMware Player and Install 2 Win 2008 Server as VM? If I would start these 2 VMs, they could already ping each other? I dont have to config the win 7 system, only the VM servers right? Or do I need something else? Thank you

Edit: Thread closed, ouch :/ But to the other people: thank you for the fast answers, I will try it.

Comment: Just remember that VMWare Player is not licensed for commercial use

Comment: I disagree with the closing of the question, just because you're new to servers, doesn't invalidate the question. We all needed to know how to build a testing lab at some stage.

Comment: Hi Mark, no I wont use it for commercial stuff. Its just to learn new things and see what else I could do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the server world.  You can certainly use VMWare player to build your own labs.  You can also use the microsoft labs if you don't have time (or resources) to build your own. See [technet virtual labs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/virtuallabs/bb512925) for 2008r2 labs, there are of course others as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it with VMWare Player. The paid enterprise offerings offer administration, reliability, etc. features but it's entirely possible to setup a test environment with the basic consumer-side offerings. Obviously, running such a setup in production wouldn't be much fun.

Answer (score 1):

VMware Player can do that, but be careful with hardware resources. Windows Server 2008 R2, even on a low-load server, can get quite heavy on RAM usage, and it's definitely not a fun experience to have to run it on a single-CPU VM.

In a pinch, a Windows Server 2008 R2 server can run with 1 GB and 1 CPU, but I'd rather not even install it unless I could give it at least 2 GB and 2 CPUs. And this can be difficult to do for 2 or more VM on a consumer-level PC.

Comment: It really depends on the load- I've run 2k8 on 512Mb of ram with 1 CPU as a DC for a lab.

Comment: But it's not a pleasant experience *at all*. There really are times when I'd want my WS2003 DCs back... WS2008R2 is far better in many ways, but it's *really* a lot more bloated. Oh, well, I suppose that's the "progress"...